# Non-polynomial $C^{\infty}$ function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with rational values for rational arguments?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Let's say that $ \ f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \ $ and $ \ f \ $ is  $C^{\infty}$ function.

Assume that for every $ \ x \in \mathbb{Q} \ $ we have also $ \ f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Are the polynomials the only such functions?

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/48910/smooth-functions-for-which-fx-is-rational-if-and-only-if-x-is-rational

Comment: Ah, I forgot to thank you few months ago @Listing, your comment solves my problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the same property with a rational function, such as $f(x) = (1+x^2)^{-1}$.  Just make sure none of the poles are on the real line.